# i am having trouble with the kick command in my bot, can anyone help me?

Tags: discord.js

edit
So i tried to make a kick and ban command but then i got this error in my kick file idk how to fix it

```js
const memberTarget = message.guild.member.cache.get(member.id);
                     ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

this is the code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "this command kicks people",
    execute(messages, args){
        const member = messages.mentions.users.first();
        if(member){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.member.cache.get(member.id);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("bing bong he is gone!");
        }else{
            message.channel.send('you couldent kick that person');
        }
    }
}
```

edit: now i got this error
const memberTarget = message.guild.member.cache.get(member.id);
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Change `execute(messages, args){` to `execute(message, args){`

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your error:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "this command kicks people",
    execute(message, args){
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(member){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.member(member);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("bing bong he is gone!");
        }else{
            message.channel.send('you couldent kick that person');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of command i put commands and i still got the same error

Comment: No you have to put `command` instead of `commands` as I described in my answer.

Comment: ok in client.command.get('kick').execute(message, args) i put command instead of commands and i got this error now: client.command.get('kick').execute(message, args);
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: No the error you described in your question occurs in the if statement. My answer is the answer to your question.

Comment: yes and you said to put command instead of commands when i already had command in
if(command ==='kick'){

Comment: Yes thats what I said in my answer. I've edited my answer. That's how your code should look like.

Comment: ok i put the code and now i get a error in my kick.js file

Comment: Ok then you have an error in the kick command code. Please edit your question.

Comment: For me this does work. Anyways edited my answer again ^^

Comment: i still get the error but this time he says the thing and the bot stays online, the only thing now is that he dosent kick the person and it also says DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions-extended.html#limitations-and-oddities

Comment: Good but now your command works. Just fix the permissions error with the link I commented ^^

Comment: i forgot to also give him admin role but now it works, ty so much for the support!

Comment: No problem make sure that your ban command works also ^^